# React- leaflet i can import icon from public folder, but not from component folder

Tags: reactjs

When I import my icons like that

```
 Icon =new L.icon({
  iconUrl: require(`../data/icons/typescript.svg`),
  iconSize: new L.Point(60, 75),
  className: 'leaflet-div-icon'
 });
```

I get no errors in compilator, but my icons are not showing on map

It works only when I put icons in public folder in my react project, then the code looks like this

```
 Icon =new L.icon({
iconUrl: `/icons/typescript.svg`,
iconSize: new L.Point(60, 75),
   className: 'leaflet-div-icon'
  });
```

Comment: Try if this works `iconUrl: require('/icons/' + this.skill + '.svg').default,`

Answer (score 0):

Import the file using [require](https://blog.bitsrc.io/javascript-require-vs-import-47827a361b77) and use like this

`iconUrl: require('/icons/' + this.skill + '.svg').default,`